# How do I correctly cast List in wrapper class?

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I am receiving the following error in my Apex runtime:

```
JSONException: Expected List<ApexBatch.SFError> but found {
```

It's do with how I'm assigning the response to my wrapper but I'm not sure how I need to parse:

Wrapper Classes

```
public class CustomResponse {
   public boolean isSuccess;
   public List<CustomError> errors;
}

public class CustomError {
    public String Id;
    public String error;
}
```

Example JSON Response:

```
{"IsSuccess":false,"Errors":{}}
```

... and heres one **with** errors:

```
{"isSuccess":true,"Errors":{"123":"error code here", "123":"error code here"}}
```

Apex which assigns to wrapper:

```
    CustomResponse calloutBody = (CustomResponse)JSON.deserialize(
response.getBody(), CustomResponse.class);
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong exactly so I can learn from it.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? You're JSON contains an Object in the Error property, and not an Array

Comment: Sorry I forgot to attach, I've updated my question now.

Comment: Do you have any examples of JSONs that contain actual errors?

Comment: You are declaring the `errors` as list, whereas the attribute `Errors` in your JSON is not an array.

Comment: @Folkert Updated

Comment: You're JSON doesn't contain a list, but an object. It needs to change to ```{"isSuccess":true,"Errors":[{"123":"error code here"}, {"123":"error code here"}]}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrapper class that you have expects an array of `Errors` as that's how you have declared it in your class as `public List<CustomError> errors;` which in turn has two attributes namely `Id` and `error`.

The JSON in that case should be something as below, so that when you deserialize the JSON, it maps back to your wrapper class.

```
{
  "IsSuccess":false,
  "Errors":[{"Id":"123", "error":"my error message"}]
}
```

If the `Errrors` attribute on the JSON itself is not expected to be an array, then you need to modify your wrapper class accordingly.

Comment: How can I correctly handle when Errors list is empty?

Comment: In that case, you should get that attribute in the response as `"Errors":[]`

Comment: @DeploymentFailure you can omit it entirely (errors will be null), or use the null keyword (`"errors":null`, no quotes around null), or `"errors":[]`, which would be a non-null empty list.